# Div style in C# code

Tags: c#

Is it possible to put div styles in a C# label control? Working with iTextSharp.

```
var background = new Label
{
        Text = "<div style='margin-left: 40px;'>" + "<br/><b><u>" + LabelBackground.Text + "</u></b><br/>" + "<b>" + LabelDoB.Text + "</b>" + LabelDoBFromDb.Text +
                                                 "<br/>" + "<b>" + LabelPhone.Text + "</b>" + LabelPhoneFromDb.Text + "<br/>" + "<b>" + LabelEmail.Text + "</b>" +
                                                 LabelEmailFromDb.Text + "<br/>" + "<b>" + LabelPosition.Text + "</b>" +
                                                 LabelPositionFromDb.Text + "<br/>" + "</div>"
};
```

My `<br/>` tags works, but not the `<div>`

Whole code:

```
            //Create Document class object and set its size to letter and give space left, right, Top, Bottom Margin
            Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 42, 35);

            try
            {
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("c:\\Test11." + DropDownListDownload.SelectedItem.Text, FileMode.Create));
                var sv = new StringWriter();
                doc.Open();//Open Document to write 

                var hTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sv);

                var background = new Label
                                     {
                                         Text = "<div style='margin-left: 40px;'>" + "<br/><b><u>" + LabelBackground.Text + "</u></b><br/>" + "<b>" + LabelDoB.Text + "</b>" + LabelDoBFromDb.Text +
                                             "<br/>" + "<b>" + LabelPhone.Text + "</b>" + LabelPhoneFromDb.Text + "<br/>" + "<b>" + LabelEmail.Text + "</b>" +
                                             LabelEmailFromDb.Text + "<br/>" + "<b>" + LabelPosition.Text + "</b>" +
                                             LabelPositionFromDb.Text + "<br/>" + "</div>"
                                     };
                background.RenderControl(hTextWriter);

                //LANGUAGES
                string languages = string.Empty;
                var lbLanguages = new Label();
                foreach (var vLang in BulletedListLanguages.Items)
                {
                    languages += vLang + "<br/>";
                }

                lbLanguages.Text = "<br/><b><u>" + LabelLanguages.Text + "</u></b><br/>" + languages;
                lbLanguages.RenderControl(hTextWriter);

                String strHtml1 = sv.ToString();

                var hw = new HTMLWorker(doc);
                hw.Parse(new StringReader(strHtml1));
            }

            finally
            {
                doc.Close();
            }
```

Comment: ASP.NET or what do you want to do?

Comment: @bash.d, I'm rendering my information to a PDF document, all works fine but i don't really know how to put a style on it. Working with iTextSharp, want me to put my whole code inside?

Comment: Well, not my kind of stuff, but other people might help. SO, go ahead!

Answer (score 1):

i think its better to add `asp:Literal` in this case. so the default asp styling for the Label wont be a problem.

Comment: or use `CssClass` and apply class using normal css.

Comment: +1 for using "asp:literal" . This is easy to use and more logic

Answer (score 0):

You can add  tags to some controls (check out the 'literal' tag for your needs), however,  you may find it better to add the class using the [CssClass property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx).

```
Label label = new Label();
label.CssClass="class";
label.Text = "My content";
```

Answer (score 0):

You're putting a `<div>` in a label, which is a bad idea in terms of semantics. What I'd do, personally, is make a `Panel` tag, which renders a `<div`> anyway.

i.e.

```
var background = new Panel();

var text = new Literal
{
        Text = "<br/><b><u>" + LabelBackground.Text + "</u></b><br/>" + "<b>" + LabelDoB.Text + "</b>" + LabelDoBFromDb.Text +
                                                 "<br/>" + "<b>" + LabelPhone.Text + "</b>" + LabelPhoneFromDb.Text + "<br/>" + "<b>" + LabelEmail.Text + "</b>" +
                                                 LabelEmailFromDb.Text + "<br/>" + "<b>" + LabelPosition.Text + "</b>" +
                                                 LabelPositionFromDb.Text + "<br/>"
};

background.Controls.Add(text);

background.Attributes["margin-left"] = "40px"; // Preferably, I'd add a class and do this plainly in CSS.
```

And, it's up to you how you do it, but in terms of code maintainability and design, I'd do it like this:

(aspx)

```
<div style="margin-left: 40px">
    <br/><b><u><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="DisplayLabelBackground" /></u></b> // etc, but I *definitely* wouldn't use <b> and <u> tags either
</div>
```

Then, in your code beind:

```
DisplayLabelBackground.Text = LabelBackground.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

asp:Label render a span which is an inline tag. So you can't put a div in a span. You can replace your Label by a simple div with runat server and put your text with InnerHtml or InnerText attribute

aspx

```
<div id="myDiv" runat="server" style="margin-left:40px"></div>
```

aspx.cs

```
myDiv.InnerHtml = "..."
```